# Ionic CLI won't give the proper behavior on command line with option

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-cli

I have a new M2 Mac Mini, so after i set up my env its work normal,
but when i use

`ionic build --prod`

or

`ionic serve --lab`

it doesn't showing the expected behavior.
it just buildin on dev env, or serve normally like `ionic serve`
Already use ionic 7.1.1 and then downgrade to 7.0.0 still not solving this problem, maybe is there any step that i missing ?

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 7.0.0 (/Users/stevenpu/.nvm/versions/node/v20.5.1/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.7.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 14.2.12
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 14.2.11
   @angular/cli                  : 14.2.11
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 5.3.0
   @capacitor/android : 5.3.0
   @capacitor/core    : 5.3.0
   @capacitor/ios     : 5.3.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 11.1.0
   Cordova Platforms : none
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed globally
   native-run  : 1.7.2

System:

   NodeJS : v20.5.1 (/Users/stevenpu/.nvm/versions/node/v20.5.1/bin/node)
   npm    : 10.0.0
   OS     : macOS Unknown
   Xcode  : Xcode 14.3.1 Build version 14E300c
```

Comment: "lab was deprecated last year and removed in @ionic/cli 7.0.0" - https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-lab-not-working/233264/3

For build you can try - ionic capacitor build ios --prod

Comment: it does work somehow, but i want to know why does when im using this code `ionic build -—prod; npx cap copy ; npx cap sync ; npx cap open android;` doesn't work on my mac ? but working on my windows. Is there any differential ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77036110/ionic-cli-wont-give-the-proper-behavior-on-command-line-with-option#comment135805741_77036110), `--lab` is deprecated. But `--prod` should work.

If you are using it like this:`ionic build -—prod; npx cap copy ;`, then it won't have any effect. because `npx cap copy` builds the project first and override your previous build. you should use it like this:

```
npx cap copy --prod
```

`npx cap sync` has the same situation. they both build the project first. and if it works like this somewhere else, there might be a versioning problem.

However, if these are not your case, please specify what is your expected behaviour and how is it failing to achieve that.